# Python script not starting from Jenkins pipeline via pm2 start command

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pm2

I'm trying to set up my Jenkins pipeline to run a pm2 start command during the Deploy step. The pm2 start command is in a Bash script and runs my Python program using pm2. Each time I run the build manually, the Jenkins console reports that the build succeeded and the console output shows that pm2 has started the Python program and a PID is assigned to it.

Here are the last few lines of the Jenkins build console output:

```
+ ./start_pm2.sh
[PM2] Starting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/rocket-league-tourney-bot/rocket_league_tourney_bot.py in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
┌─────┬──────────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name                         │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼──────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ rocket_league_tourney_bot    │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 28304    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 6.3mb    │ jenkins  │ disabled │
└─────┴──────────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

However, if I login to the remote machine (AWS EC2 instance), I see that the PID assigned by pm2 does not exist and the program is not running.

I checked the PID and ran `pm2 list` as the jenkins user and I see that it has stopped:

```
[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx logs]# ps -s 28304
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx logs]# runuser -u jenkins pm2 list
┌─────┬──────────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name                         │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼──────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ rocket_league_tourney_bot    │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 0        │ 0      │ 0    │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ jenkins  │ disabled │
└─────┴──────────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

The pm2 logs are not helpful either:

```
[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx logs]# runuser -u jenkins pm2 log
[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)
/var/lib/jenkins/.pm2/pm2.log last 15 lines:
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:42:47: PM2 log: App [rocket_league_tourney_bot:0] online
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:44:28: PM2 log: Stopping app:rocket_league_tourney_bot id:0
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:44:28: PM2 log: App [rocket_league_tourney_bot:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:44:28: PM2 log: pid=27651 msg=process killed
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:47:47: PM2 log: App [rocket_league_tourney_bot:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:47:47: PM2 log: App [rocket_league_tourney_bot:0] online
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:48:03: PM2 log: Stopping app:rocket_league_tourney_bot id:0
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:48:03: PM2 log: App [rocket_league_tourney_bot:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:48:03: PM2 log: pid=27739 msg=process killed
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:50:37: PM2 log: App [rocket_league_tourney_bot:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:50:37: PM2 log: App [rocket_league_tourney_bot:0] online
PM2        | 2021-09-23T18:50:37: PM2 log: App [rocket_league_tourney_bot:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]
PM2        | 2021-09-23T19:00:31: PM2 log: App [rocket_league_tourney_bot:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-09-23T19:00:31: PM2 log: App [rocket_league_tourney_bot:0] online
PM2        | 2021-09-23T19:00:31: PM2 log: App [rocket_league_tourney_bot:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]

/var/lib/jenkins/.pm2/logs/rocket-league-tourney-bot-out.log last 15 lines:
/var/lib/jenkins/.pm2/logs/rocket-league-tourney-bot-error.log last 15 lines:
```

Both the out and error log files are empty.

I verified that the environment variables and Python/Pip are in scope for the jenkins user. What could be going on? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like when the build is done, Jenkins is killing everything it started. (Cleaning up after itself.) See this question/answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/502593/starting-a-forever-process-in-a-jenkins-build-step

Comment: I set the `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe` and `JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe python3` in my Jenkins build step, but it's still not working. Should this be before pm2 start or after?

Comment: I would try `export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe`  then `export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe` then `./start_pm2.sh &` where each command is on a separate line.

Comment: This is my deploy step, with those changes, and it's still not working..
`
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
                sh "export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe"
                sh "export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe"
                sh "chmod +x ./start_pm2.sh"
                sh "chmod +x ./stop_pm2.sh"
                sh "./stop_pm2.sh || true"
                sh "./start_pm2.sh"
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Jenkins starts a shell instance (`bash`) that runs `./start_pm2.sh` which in turn runs `pm2` in "fork mode". The parent of `pm2` is your `bash` instance.

Once the script is done, the `bash` process is killed, and any of its children are killed too, including your `pm2` process.

If this is the case, to prevent this from happening, either start `pm2` in non-fork mode and wait for it to complete, or modify your script to start a detached instance of `pm2` that doesn't have `bash` as its parent.

You may want to read up on `nohup` and `daemonize` as possible solutions to achieve that.

Comment: Not sure if I checked correctly, but according to `ps -f`, the parent process of `pm2` has PID 1, which is `systemd`